# Strange error when connecting to Gmail IMAP

Tags: gmail, jakarta-mail, imap

```
    public List<Email> getMessages() {
        Store store = null;
        Folder inbox = null;
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        try {
            store = session.getStore();
            store.connect(IMAP_SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();
            log.debug("{} messages received", messages.length);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            log.error("Unable to connect to server {}:{}", IMAP_SERVER, IMAP_PORT);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (inbox != null && inbox.isOpen()) {
                    inbox.close(true);
                }
                if (store != null) {
                    store.close();
                }
            } catch (MessagingException me) {
                log.error("Unable to cleanly close mail connection.", me);
            }
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
```

Gives response:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.equals(Object)" because "this.status" is null
> at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.store.imap.connection.IMAPTaggedResponse.isBAD(IMAPTaggedResponse.java:86) ~[geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail-1.8.4.jar:1.8.4]
> at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.store.imap.connection.IMAPConnection.receiveResponse(IMAPConnection.java:410) ~[geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail-1.8.4.jar:1.8.4]
> at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.store.imap.connection.IMAPConnection.sendCommand(IMAPConnection.java:324) ~[geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail-1.8.4.jar:1.8.4]
> at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.store.imap.connection.IMAPConnection.processLogin(IMAPConnection.java:598) ~[geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail-1.8.4.jar:1.8.4]
> at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.store.imap.connection.IMAPConnection.processPlainAuthentication(IMAPConnection.java:537) ~[geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail-1.8.4.jar:1.8.4]
> at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.store.imap.connection.IMAPConnection.login(IMAPConnection.java:488) ~[geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail-1.8.4.jar:1.8.4]
> at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.store.imap.connection.IMAPConnection.protocolConnect(IMAPConnection.java:176) ~[geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail-1.8.4.jar:1.8.4]
> at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.store.imap.connection.IMAPConnectionPool.createPoolConnection(IMAPConnectionPool.java:211) ~[geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail-1.8.4.jar:1.8.4]
> at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.store.imap.connection.IMAPConnectionPool.protocolConnect(IMAPConnectionPool.java:177) ~[geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail-1.8.4.jar:1.8.4]
> at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.store.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:156) ~[geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail-1.8.4.jar:1.8.4]
> at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:251) ~[geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail-1.8.4.jar:1.8.4]
> at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:91) ~[geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail-1.8.4.jar:1.8.4]

Comment: Is there a question here?

You should start debugging by figuring out how to enable protocol tracing in your library, so you can see what it sent and what the server sent back.